# React native 0.60 social login issues

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react native 0.60,react 16.8 with firebase authentication (using package react-native-firebase). We are using react-native-fbsdk for facebook login and react-native-google-signin. It is giving me the following errors.

- "Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'".
- "Unable to find a matching configuration of project
  :react-native-google-signin: - None of the consumable configurations
        have attributes."

Comment: Is this an error after the module has been installed?

Comment: We recently upgraded to 0.6 with the help of this guys https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SvV7BM5iYw . Hope it helps.

Comment: @hongdevelop react-native-google-signin was successfully installed but giving the above errors while creating a build, and react-native-fbsdk is giving errors in installations

Comment: 'react-native-google-signin' module did not run properly, of course 'react-native-fbsdk' cannot be installed. What error occurs when installing and building the 'react-native-google-signin' module?

Comment: @hongdevelop on adding google-signin it was saying the following errors - 1. "Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'". 2. Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-google-signin: - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/docs/android-guide.md

Comment: Google-signin issues are resolved but I am still getting issues with facebook . signInWithCredential is not working